# Hoogle query returning functions that don't match type signature

Tags: haskell, hoogle

If I try to use the following [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hoogle) command (v4.2.33) to search for functions containing the type signature `ByteString->[ByteString]` :

```
hoogle --count 40 "ByteString->[ByteString]"
```

then towards the end of the output I get :

```
Data.ByteString.Char8 transpose :: [ByteString] -> [ByteString]
Data.ByteString.Lazy transpose :: [ByteString] -> [ByteString]
Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 transpose :: [ByteString] -> [ByteString]
Codec.Compression.Zlib.Raw compress :: ByteString -> ByteString
Codec.Compression.GZip compress :: ByteString -> ByteString
```

Why does Hoogle return functions with signature `ByteString -> ByteString` etc. when I specify the type signature to be `ByteString->[ByteString]`?

Comment: Hoogle does some kind of a fuzzy match.

Comment: Presumably because these functions could be used to implement functions of the type you need, and if you really don't want them you can just ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoogle uses a concept of "[approximate"](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/f/f0/TMR-Issue12.pdf#page=27) type matching, generalizing types and stripping constructors to find close matches.